# How to calculate the integral $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dz}{\sqrt[3]{(1-z)(1+z)^2}}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

The integral is $I=\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1}\dfrac{dz}{\sqrt[3]{(1-z)(1+z)^2}}$. I used Mathematica to calculate, the result was $\dfrac{2\pi}{\sqrt{3}}$, I think it may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\int_{-1}^{1}{\dd z \over \root[3]{\pars{1 - z}\pars{1 + z}^{2}}}
     =\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{2}z^{-2/3}\pars{2 - z}^{-1/3}\,\dd z}:\
     {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}&\int_{2}^{0}\!\!z^{-2/3}\expo{\pars{-2/3}0\ic}
> \pars{2 - z}^{-1/3}\expo{\pars{-1/3}2\pi\ic}\,\dd z
> +\int_{0}^{2}\!z^{-2/3}\expo{\pars{-2/3}0\ic}
> \pars{2 - z}^{-1/3}\expo{\pars{-1/3}0\ic}\,\dd z
> \\[3mm]&=\pars{-\expo{-2\pi\ic/3} + 1}
> \color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{2}z^{-2/3}\pars{2 - z}^{-1/3}\,\dd z}
> =-2\pi\ic\,{\rm Res}_{z\ =\ 0}\bracks{%
> -\,{1 \over z^{2}}\,z^{2/3}\pars{2 - {1 \over z}}^{-1/3}}
> \\[3mm]&=2\pi\ic\,{\rm Res}_{z\ =\ 0}\bracks{{\pars{2z - 1}^{-1/3} \over z}}
> =2\pi\ic\,{\rm Res}_{z\ =\ 0}
> \bracks{{\verts{2z - 1}^{-1/3}\expo{\pars{-1/3}\pi\ic} \over z}}
> =2\pi\ic\expo{-\pi\ic/3}
> \end{align}

\begin{align}
&\color{#00f}{\large%
\int_{-1}^{1}{\dd z \over \root[3]{\pars{1 - z}\pars{1 + z}^{2}}}}
=\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{2}z^{-2/3}\pars{2 - z}^{-1/3}\,\dd z}
={2\pi\ic\expo{-\pi\ic/3} \over -\expo{-2\pi\ic/3} + 1}
\\[3mm]&=\pi\,{2\ic \over \expo{\pi\ic/3} - \expo{-\pi\ic/3}}
={\pi \over \sin\pars{\pi/3}} = {\pi \over \root{3}/2}
=\color{#00f}{\large{2\root{3} \over 3}\,\pi}\ \approx {\tt 3.6276}
\end{align}

Comment: Your answer is great, actually it's a question of complex analysis. And I need this kind of answer.

Comment: @Nix It's similar to [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration#Example_.28VI.29_.E2.80.93_logarithms_and_the_residue_at_infinity) . It's nice it was useful for you.

Answer (score 10):

**Hint :**

Putting $z=2t-1$ yields
$$
\int_{-1}^{1}\dfrac{dz}{\sqrt[\Large3]{(1-z)(1+z)^2}}=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{dt}{\sqrt[\Large3]{(1-t)t^2}}=\int_{0}^{1} t^{\large-\frac23}(1-t)^{\large-\frac13}\ dt,
$$
then use [Beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and [Euler's reflection formula for the gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General).

Answer (score 5):

Rearrange the integral

$$\int \frac{1}{1+z}\sqrt[3]{\frac{1+z}{1-z}}dz$$

Now set $$t^3=\frac{1+z}{1-z}$$

so 
$$z=\frac{t^3-1}{t^3+1}=1-\frac{2}{t^3+1}$$

$$dz=\frac{6t^2}{(t^3+1)^2}dt$$

And the integral becomes

$$\int \frac{1}{1+z}\sqrt[3]{\frac{1+z}{1-z}}dz=\int \frac{t^3+1}{2t^3}t\frac{6t^2}{(t^3+1)^2}dt=\int \frac{3}{t^3+1}dt
$$

Taking the limits into account, 
$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{1+z}\sqrt[3]{\frac{1+z}{1-z}}dz=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{3}{t^3+1}dt
$$

Note that 
$$\frac{3}{t^3+1}=\frac{1}{t+1}-\frac{t-2}{t^2-t+1}=
\frac{1}{t+1}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{2t-1}{t^2-t+1}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{t^2-t+1}$$

Now 
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{t+1}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{2t-1}{t^2-t+1}dt=\ln\left(\frac{t+1}{\sqrt{t^2-1+1}}\right) |_0^{\infty}=0$$

(how do you make the long line for the integral ?)

That leaves $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{t^2-t+1}dt
=\frac{3}{2} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{(t-\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}}dt
=\sqrt{3} \arctan \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} (t-\frac{1}{2})|_0^{\infty}=
\sqrt{3}(\arctan (\infty)-\arctan (-\frac{1}{\sqrt3})=\sqrt{3}(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{6})=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Perform the change of variable $z = \frac{1-t^3}{1+t^3}$ (where $t$ now ranges from $+\infty$ to $0$).  The integral simplifies and becomes $I = 3\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{t\,dt}{1+t^3}$ and this is easy to compute (the antiderivative of $\frac{t}{1+t^3}$ is $\log\frac{\sqrt{1-t+t^2}}{1+t} + \sqrt{3}\arctan\frac{-1+2t}{\sqrt{3}}$).  The same change of variables allows us to compute the original integral with arbitrary bounds.

But, more interestingly, how did I know which change of variable to perform to reduce this integral to a rational function?  Well, consider the plane algebraic curve with equation $y^3 = (1-z)(1+z)^2$: it is a cubic curve with a singularity at $(z,y) = (-1,0)$, which implies that a straight line of varying slope through this point (i.e., a line with equation $y=t(1+z)$ where $t$ is the slope) will cut the curve at $(-1,0)$ with multiplicity $2$ and a third point, depending on the slope $t$, with multiplicity $1$, which parametrizes the curve rationally: so, in practice, substitute $y=t(1+z)$ inside $y^3 = (1-z)(1+z)^2$, factor out the $(1+z)^2$ and we are left with $z=\frac{1-t^3}{1+t^3}$ and $y=\frac{2t}{1+t^3}$ as parametrization of the curve $y^3 = (1-z)(1+z)^2$.  But now this gives us the change of variable we need (the curve being parametrized by rational functions, the original integral of $\frac{dz}{y}$ will be the integral of a rational function, in this case $-3\frac{t\,dt}{1+t^3}$).